# Spectrum of a labelled complete graph $K_n$

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Suppose, $K_n$ is a complete simple graph with each edge label $k$. Then its adjacency matrix $A(K_n)$ has all the entries zero along the diagonal, and each non-diagonal entries are $k$.

> What  are the eigenvalues or, the spectrum of $K_n$? Is there any known formula for this?

Comment: Well, you know that since the sum of each row is $(n-1)k$, then it is an eigenvalue. Maybe there's more, that's just the first thing that comes in mind.

Comment: @GSofer Still, I couldn't figure out as how is this question duplicate? It seems like finding all $n$ Eigen values remained a difficult problem for me. Well do you mean that all the Eigenvalues will be $(n-1)k$ in this case? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: this is definitely an interesting problem, off the top of my head I'm not sure what are the remaining eigenvalues, this was just the first thing that came to mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is your matrix, then $A+kI$ is the matrix where all entries are $k$'s, which has rank $1$. Therefore $-k$ is an eigenvalue of your matrix with multiplicity $n-1$.

(In general, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $m$ if the rank of $A - \lambda I$ is $n-m$.)

This gives us all but one of the eigenvalues. But we know that the trace of $A$ is $0$, so the eigenvalues have to add up to $0$. If $n-1$ of them are $-k$, then the remaining one should be $(n-1)k$.

Comment: Well. It means that the spectrum will be $\lbrace (n-1)k, -k, -k, ..., -k\rbrace$, i. e.  $-k$ repeats $(n-1)$ times. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what it will be.